# Creating flow or model programmatically

Tags: mule

I want to create a flow or model dynamically without using mule-config.xml for tcp with remote machines.

It should be something like this:

```
MuleContext context = new DefaultMuleContextFactory().createMuleContext();
MuleRegistry registry = context.getRegistry();

EndpointBuilder testEndpointBuilder = new EndpointURIEndpointBuilder("vm://testFlow.in",
    context);
testEndpointBuilder.setExchangePattern(MessageExchangePattern.REQUEST_RESPONSE);
registry.registerEndpointBuilder("testFlow.in", testEndpointBuilder);

InboundEndpoint vmInboundEndpoint = testEndpointBuilder.buildInboundEndpoint();
registry.registerEndpoint(vmInboundEndpoint);

StringAppendTransformer stringAppendTransformer = new StringAppendTransformer(" world");
stringAppendTransformer.setMuleContext(context);

Flow testFlow = new Flow("testFlow", context);
testFlow.setMessageSource(vmInboundEndpoint);
testFlow.setMessageProcessors(Arrays.asList((MessageProcessor) stringAppendTransformer));
registry.registerFlowConstruct(testFlow);

context.start();

MuleClient muleClient = new MuleClient(context);
MuleMessage response = muleClient.send("vm://testFlow.in", "hello", null);
Validate.isTrue(response.getPayloadAsString().equals("hello world"));

muleClient.dispose();
context.stop();
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: Hi,I dont want to use the mule-config.xml, i want to do the inbound and out bound programatically

Comment: Still: what is the problem? I only see a snippet of code but no error or actual question. You need to be clear.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your problem, but if you need a tcp outbound endpoint in your flow, you just create it similarly like the inbound vm endpoint in the example, but you then add it to a certain point in the flow in a list with all the processors with setMessageProcessors, like in the example where stringAppendTransformer is wrapped inside a list and added to the flow.

The code to create your tcp outbound would be something like this:

```
String address = "tcp://localhost:1234";
EndpointURIEndpointBuilder builder = new 
   EndpointURIEndpointBuilder(new URIBuilder(address), context);
builder.setExchangePattern(MessageExchangePattern.REQUEST_RESPONSE);
registry.registerEndpointBuilder("testFlow.out", builder);

OutboundEndpoint tcpOutboundEndpoint = builder.buildOutboundEndpoint();
registry.registerEndpoint(tcpOutboundEndpoint);
```

UPDATE regarding your new comment:

using a Java component:

```
//object factory for your Java class
PrototypeObjectFactory objectFactory = new PrototypeObjectFactory(MyClass.class);
objectFactory.initialise();
//the actual component
DefaultJavaComponent component = new DefaultJavaComponent(objectFactory);
//entry point resolver to determine the called method
EntryPointResolver resolver = new ExplicitMethodEntryPointResolver();
((ExplicitMethodEntryPointResolver)resolver).addMethod("myMethod");
component.setEntryPointResolvers(Arrays.asList(resolver));
```

Then add the component in the list like you add all the other processors

Comment: It is  not invoking my java component,do you have any idea to add the java commponent to the flow

Comment: That goes a bit beyond your original tcp question, but I updated my answer for this.

Comment: Dear Anton,Thanks for your input,as you had suggested I added the changes it is working properly